# Do certain consoles / genres target certain demographics in-game?

Tags: game-dev-story

While playing Game Dev Story, there are many things to customize when it comes to developing a game, such as genre, and the console you want to release it for. The consoles in-game share a ***slight resemblance*** to real life consoles. For example, there's the **Microx 480**, the **Intendro Whoops**, the **Intendro DM**, the **Sonny PlayStatus 2**, and many others.

Now when I develop a game, I like to choose the console that it would probably be on in real life. For example, when developing a `War` `Shooter` game, I would develop it on the **Sonny PlayStatus 2**, not the **Intendro Whoops**. On the other hand, when making an `Animal` `Education`, I would do the opposite.

There's also another factor - your fan base is spread among a multitude of age groups; depending on how you advertise, certain age groups will contain more fans of your company than others.

I'm curious; am I actually helping my games sell better by doing this? Would `Animal` games do better on an **Intendro** than a **Sonny** console, and `War` games not do so well on the **Intendro DM**?

As another example, say I have absolutely no fan base in any category, except for the 5 - 12 group, in which I have tons of fans. Would my **Intendro** games sell a lot better than my **Microx** games? Or maybe I have only female fans; would my `Simulation` games sell better than my `War` games?

<sub>*(Assuming all consoles have the same share of the market.)*</sub>

Comment: I always get so confused reading the titles of questions regarding this game.  I keep thinking they mean in the real world, and I get ready to mark as subjective or not a real question...

Comment: I've not played this game, but are you sure you understand what dating games are? In my mind, they are not for 12 yo girls, but rather 18+ boys.

Comment: I suppose you're right. *edits question*

Comment: @Mark There *are* dating games for girls, too, you know. Not nearly as many, but they are quite present.

Comment: In my experience, no, but I can't verify it.

Comment: With this question are u aiming to sell more copies of your game or increase your fan base in a certain category?

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, first start by developing for a console that has more users, on the other hand, if it resembles a real-life system that failed, don't even bother. Then it all really depends on the genre(s) that are popular, the genres that you're good at, then the skill of your developers, don't be afraid to hire outside developers, and always let your developers experiment the pay off is well worth it (try for at least a 55% success rate)

Answer (score 1):

There is no mentioning of details like this in the game manual, and the game manual usually details these things pretty well.  Because of this, I have always just assumed no.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the developers had such a big idea in mind. I think it's the same, and this is why. After playing for a long long time, you get to the point where the only thing you can do to improve your sales is produce for your own console, and that console is completely default, meaning it's always the same. So it can't have any possible demographics, so I believe it's the same.

However, maybe the game itself can define a demographic, such as "Animal" can be just for children but I don't think that's the case either.

What I feel is that the only difference between the younger and the elder audiences is the difficulty with which it is acquired. I noticed that, by the end of the game, I had 999 in every category except in the last one, which wasn't possible even by spending 1 billion dollars on lunar writing advertisements. The only way I could get to 999 on 60+ was when the audiences got older.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain no but have no real idea. I believe it just depends on how many units the console has and who your fans are. 41+ guys don't generally buy many animal simulation's, and 5 year old girls don't generally buy many ninja action's. I believe it mostly depends on how many units the console has sold, for I always get more business the higher up  I go (as long as the game is close to or as good as the one before). Hope this helps! Sorry I couldn't do more.